# Powers of traces, integrals over spheres and class functions

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra

I asked this on [math.StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746724/powers-of-traces-integrals-over-spheres-and-class-functions) a while back but got no answers. I hope I'll be forgiven for the double post.

Let $V$ be a complex vector space of dimension $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb C} V = n$, equipped with a Hermitian inner product $\langle \,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\, \rangle$, and $A$ be an endomorphism of $V$. I am interested in calculating the functional
$$
\alpha_k(A) := \int_{S^{2n-1}} \langle Av, v \rangle^k \, d\mu,
$$
where $d\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure induced by the inner product and $S^{2n-1}$ is the unit sphere with respect to that product. For $k = 1$, this functional is a nonzero multiple of the trace, as shown in [some](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62358/integral-around-unit-sphere-of-inner-product) [older](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592416/reference-request-trace-integral-formula) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738314/the-trace-as-an-integral-over-a-sphere) on math.SE. These kind of integrals pop up, for example, when we try to calculate the differential form that represents the $k$-th Segre class of a Hermitian holomorphic vector bundle.

Now, I don't really know any representation theory, but by extrapolating from one of the answers to the older questions the following should make a little sense: By polarizing we see that this functional is induced by the multilinear form
$$
\alpha_k(A_1, \ldots, A_k)
= \int_{S^{2n-1}} \langle A_1v, v \rangle \cdots \langle Av_k, v \rangle \, d\mu.
$$
This form is invariant under the action of $U(n) \times \cdots \times U(n)$ ($k$ times) on $\operatorname{Aut}(V^{\oplus k})$ (by conjugation on each factor), so $\alpha_k$ should be a class function on that representation. As such, it should be a linear combination of the characters of the representation. This should mean that $\alpha_k$ is a linear combination of the multilinear forms
$$
\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}
\prod_{|J|=k} \tr(A_J),
$$
where we define $A_J = A_{j_1} \cdots A_{j_k}$ for a multiindex $J = (j_1,\ldots,j_k)$. For $k = 2$, for example, these are
$$
\tr(A_1^2), \quad \tr(A_1) \tr(A_2), \quad \tr(A_2)^2.
$$
Of course, $\alpha_k$ is a symmetric form, so there is some redundancy here ($\tr(A_1^2)$ and $\tr(A_2^2)$ must have the same coefficient in our hypothetical linear combination).

We can calculate by brute force what happens in a special case here: Suppose $k = 2$ and $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$. If $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$ and $v = \sum z_j e_j$ a vector, we then have
$$
\langle Av,v \rangle = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j |z_j|^2, \quad
\langle Av,v \rangle^2 = \sum_{j,k=1}^n \lambda_j \lambda_k |z_j|^2 |z_k|^2.
$$
Omitting some tedious calculations over the sphere, we then find that
$$
\eqalign{
\alpha_2(A) 
= \int_{S^{2n-1}} \langle Av,v \rangle^2 \,d\mu
&= \sum_{j,k=1}^n \lambda_j \lambda_k \int_{S^{2n-1}} |z_j|^2 |z_k|^2 \, d\mu
\cr
&= \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\sum_{j,k=1}^n \lambda_j \lambda_k 
+ \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j^2
\cr
&= \frac{1}{n(n+1)}( \tr(A)^2 + \tr(A^2) ),
}
$$
as we suspected. Unfortunately, this direct approach is completely hopeless for higher $k$, so we must look for other ways to calculate the integral.

**Question** Can we make my representation-theoretic hand-waiving precise to (1) show the existence of the hypothetical linear combination and (2) actually determine the coefficients in that combination?

Comment: Your calculation with $k=2$ seems to assume that the orthonormal basis $e_i$ consists of eigenvectors of $A$.  This makes $A$ normal, I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Begin by rewriting $\alpha_k(A_1,\ldots,A_k)$ as follows (just move integrals and traces around):
$$
\alpha_k(A_1,\ldots,A_k) = \mathrm{tr}\Big( (A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_k) \int_{S^{2n-1}}(vv^* \otimes \cdots \otimes vv^*) d\mu \Big).
$$

Well, the integral on the right is well-known to be $P_{sym}/\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}$, where $P_{sym}$ is the projection onto the symmetric subspace (i.e., the subspace of $V \otimes \cdots \otimes V$ spanned by vectors of the form $v \otimes \cdots \otimes v$). We thus have
$$
\alpha_k(A_1,\ldots,A_k) = \frac{1}{\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}}\mathrm{tr}\big( (A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_k) P_{sym} \big).
$$

One way to write $P_{sym}$ is as
$$
P_{sym} = \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\pi\in S_k}W_{\pi},
$$
where $W_{\pi}$ is the unitary operator that permutes the $k$ tensor factors according to the permutation $\pi$ (and $S_k$ is the symmetric group on $k$ symbols).

Thus
$$
\alpha_k(A_1,\ldots,A_k) = \frac{1}{k!\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}}\sum_{\pi\in S_k}\mathrm{tr}\big( (A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_k) W_{\pi} \big).
$$

Finally, the trace on the right can be computed in terms of traces of the $A_i$'s by breaking each $\pi$ into disjoint cycles and grouping the $A_i$'s that are within a common cycle within one trace. For example, if $\pi = (1 2)(3 4 5)$ (in cycle notation) then
$$
\mathrm{tr}\big( (A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_5) W_{\pi} \big) = \mathrm{tr}(A_1 A_2)\mathrm{tr}(A_3 A_4 A_5),
$$
and hopefully it is clear how this generalizes.

---

When $k = 2$, this gives
$$
\alpha_2(A_1,A_2) = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\big(\mathrm{tr}(A_1)\mathrm{tr}(A_2) + \mathrm{tr}(A_1A_2)\big),
$$
(the first term comes from the identity permutation, the second term comes from the transposition permutation) which agrees with the formula you found for the $k = 2$ case in your original post.

---

When $k = 3$, we get
$$
\alpha_3(A_1,A_2,A_3) = \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}\big(\mathrm{tr}(A_1)\mathrm{tr}(A_2)\mathrm{tr}(A_3) + \mathrm{tr}(A_1)\mathrm{tr}(A_2A_3) + \mathrm{tr}(A_2)\mathrm{tr}(A_1A_3)  + \mathrm{tr}(A_3)\mathrm{tr}(A_1A_2) + \mathrm{tr}(A_1A_2A_3) + \mathrm{tr}(A_3A_2A_1)\big).
$$
Again, we get one term in the sum for each of the $k! = 6$ permutations, and hopefully it is clear how they arise from the cycle decompositions of those permutations, and it generalizes to higher $k$ straightforwardly.

Comment: I think your denominator on the $k=3$ expression should be $n^3+3n^2+2n=n(n+1)(n+2)$, not $3n(n+1)$. Up to the question of scaling, it looks like $\alpha_k(A)$ is the trace of $A$ acting on $\mathrm{Sym^k}(V)$.

Comment: Whoops, thanks David. My scaling was off from very early on: everywhere that I had $2/(n(n+1))$ I should have had $1/\binom{n+1}{k}$. I will correct this now.

Comment: Its probably worth explicitly pointing out that, if the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, ..., $\lambda_n$, then $\mathrm{Tr}((A \otimes A \otimes  \cdots \otimes A) P_{sym})$ is $\sum_{k_1+\cdots+k_n=k,\ k_i \geq 0} \lambda_1^{k_1} \lambda_2^{k_2} \cdots \lambda_n^{k_n}$.