# Inequalities involving traces of products of hermitian positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: inequalities, permutations, positivity, traces, hermitian

$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$
Fix an integer $n \geq 2$. Let $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$ be hermitian positive semidefinite matrices, with each $A_i$ being $m$ by $m$.
Consider the symmetric group $S_n$ on $n$ elements. Given $\sigma \in S_n$, we can write $\sigma = c_1 \cdots c_r$ as a product of disjoint cycles $c_1, \dotsc c_r$. Given a cycle, say
$$ c = (i_1, \dotsc i_\kappa),$$
we associate to $c$ the following expression
$$ E(c) = \tr( A_{i_1} \cdots A_{i_\kappa} ). $$
We then associate to $\sigma = c_1 \cdots c_r \in S_n$ as above, the following expression
$$ E(\sigma) = \prod_{a = 1}^r E(c_a). $$

For example, if $n = 6$ and $\sigma = (12) (456)$, we get
$$ E(\sigma) = \tr(A_1 A_2) \tr(A_3) \tr(A_4 A_5 A_6).$$

I have proved the following inequality.

$$ \sum_{\sigma \in S_n \setminus \{1\}} E(\sigma) \geq 0.$$

I wonder if it is new and/or interesting.

For example, for $n = 2$, it reduces to the well known inequality
$$ \tr(A_1 A_2) \geq 0.$$

For $n = 3$, the corresponding inequality is
$$\tr(A_1 A_2) \tr(A_3) + \tr(A_2 A_3)\tr(A_1) + \tr(A_3 A_1)\tr(A_2) + \tr(A_1 A_2 A_3) + \tr(A_1 A_3 A_2) \geq 0,$$
and so on.

The proof is not very difficult but short and interesting. Kindly let me know if these inequalities (for $n \geq 3$) are new please. I have very limited access to online resources.

Note: I have almost completely cleaned up and rewritten the post. So now @AbdelMalekAbdesselam's question and my reply would not make sense to someone who is reading this post for the first time (they are related to a previous version of this post), for which I apologize. The post needed a lot of cleaning. It just had to be done.

Comment: Hi Joseph. Could you write explicitly the $2\times 2$ matrix $\pi(v)$ corresponding to a vector $v\in S^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ so one can understand your question without knowledge of Clifford algebras and their representations. Is it just $v\cdot \sigma$ where the sigmas are the Pauli matrices?

Comment: Hang on. You can think of $v$ as really $v . \sigma$. But then $\pi(v) = (1 + v.\sigma)/2$.

Comment: MathJax note: a line break after the closing `$` in `$\DeclareMathOperator\tr{tr}$` appears in the text, so must be deleted. TeX note: when aligning, `= &` does not space well; see $\begin{split} a = & b \end{split}$ `\begin{split} a = & b \end{split}`. This is fixed by inserting an apparently spurious atom: $\begin{split} a ={} & b \end{split}$ `\begin{split} a ={} & b \end{split}`. I have edited to fix both of these.

Comment: @LSpice, thank you!

Comment: In light of the answer [to this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187827/powers-of-traces-integrals-over-spheres-and-class-functions/187970#187970), your proposed inequality is equivalent to $\mathrm{tr}((A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n)(P_{\text{sym}} - I/n!)) \geq 0$, where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product and $P_{\text{sym}}$ is the orthogonal projection on to the symmetric subspace. I'm not immediately seeing why that should be true, but there's probably a slick argument.

Comment: Thank you so much @NathanielJohnston for the really interesting linked discussion. You basically wrote a proof of positivity for my LHS + the term that I leave out and the argument is really nice. I obtain a slightly stronger inequality though. My argument is nice too, though more algebraic.